# What does gidNumber in phpLDAPadmin mean?

Tags: ldap

I am new to openLDAP.

When I create a new user (generic user), there is a field GID number.
Can somebody explain what this field means?

Does this number needs to be unique? I can select between my posixGroups.

I have the same posixgroups in each country (OU): users, admin, linux. 
When I have the list of posixGroups in the GIDnumber, there I cannot see which group from which ou I need to select? How can I solve this?

When you select a posixsgroup for a new user. When I go to that selected group, how can I see that the new user is a member of that group?

Kr,

Joeri

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With the gidNumber-attribute you can set the primary group of a user. That group will be used for instance when the user creates a file in a unix-like filesystem in that the file will belong to that group. And it doesn't need to be unique.

As you created the same group names under different subtrees there is no easy way to differentiate between those equally named groups. Easiest solution would be to rename those groups to include a hint to the subtree. But to be honest Personally I'd see whether it is necessary to have the same group in different subtrees and try to consilidate that to only three groups.